# I cannot fetch a mail using imap in python

Tags: python, python-3.7

The `fetch` method gives this error:

> imaplib.IMAP4.error: FETCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']

I am not attaching all of my code. I want to get the unseen msg using imap to get the body and save it as text and then download the attachment.

```
import imaplib, email, os
user= "test9101997"
password="Monday@123"
imap_url="imap.gmail.com"
attach_dir='E:\PROJECT\attachment'
filePath='D:\ATTACH'     
con=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
con.login(user,password)
con.select('INBOX')
#UIDs=con.search(None,'UNSEEN')
#print(UIDs)
(result, messages) = con.search(None, 'UnSeen')
if result == "OK":
   for message in messages:
        try: 
          ret, data =con.fetch(message,'(RFC822)')
        except:
             print ("No new emails to read.")
                    #self.close_connection()
                    #exit()
                    #result, data=con.fetch(i,'(RFC822)')
             raw=email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
```

Comment: What is the value of `message`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confused about the return value of `con.search()`.  If you take a look at the value of `messages` after that call (assuming that `result` is `OK`), it's collection of strings, not a list of message ids.  That is, after a call like:

```
result, messages = con.search(None, 'UnSeen')
```

The value of `messages` may look something like:

```
['1 2 15 20']
```

So when you try to iterate over it like this:

```
for message in messages:
```

The value of message in the first loop iteration will be `1 2 15 20`, and that's why you're getting the command error: the request you're making doesn't make any sense.  You'll want to do something like this instead:

```
(result, blocks) = con.search(None, 'UnSeen')

if result == "OK":
    for messages in blocks:
        for message in messages.split():
            ret, data = con.fetch(message, '(RFC822)')
            raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
```

There's really no good reason for the `imaplib` module to return data in this fashion.

Comment: Without seeing the code you're running it's hard to figure out what's going on. I actually ran the above code locally and it works fine; the only line referencing the `data` variable happens right after `data` is defined.

Comment: thanks for the guidance is there any way i can access the windows sticky note and write to it using python

Comment: I have no idea. That seems like something you should post in a different question.